# Spaces where a point is always a limit point of any of its neighborhoods

Tags: general-topology

Let $ X $ be a topological space. Let $ U $ be an open subset of $ X $, and pick some $ x\in U $.

If $ X = \mathbb R $, then $ x $ is not isolated, but in general this is not the case (any discrete space provides a counterexample).

My question is if there are there any "well-known" and "convenient" requirements on the topology of $ X $ under which a point is always a limit point of any of its neighborhoods. (For example, being Hausdorff alone can't be such a requirement on $ X $, since discrete spaces are Hausdorff in the majority of cases).

Comment: Have you tried thinking about whether this can happen if $x$ is not isolated?

Comment: Such a space is called *crowded*: $T_1$ and no isolated points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A space $X$ is called a "crowded space" if it's $T_1$ and has no isolated points.

In a crowded space, all open sets are infinite and every $x$ is a limit point of any of its neighbourhoods, as is easy to see.

(the crowdedness is not a necessary condition, just a common convenient one; an indiscrete space of two or more points also has the property that every point is a limit point of any of its neighbourhoods, trivially).

If $X$ has your property and has two or more points, it cannot have isolated points. A space without isolated points is often called dense-in-itself.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Could you provide me a "concrete" example of a space that is not crowded (and not discrete, obviously)? I tried to think of one, but my knowledge of topology is limited to what is taught in analysis courses (and in any case I'm not exactly a genius either ahha).

Comment: @giovanniadeodato $\{0\} \cup \{\frac1n\mid n \=1,2,\ldots\}\subseteq \Bbb R$ is an example.